# Incorrect Paschen Curve for Breakdown Being Generated

Tags: material-science, plasma-physics

I'm trying to reproduce a Paschen curve for hydrogen gas (H2) as the wiki page shows. I got a nice looking curve to plot in Matlab but the issue is, it is very wrong. The curve I get does not agree with either the theoretical curve generated on the wiki page, nor data from experiment (The data from experiment and wiki page plots agree so those I assume are the correct ones). Could someone take a look at what I have done here and point out the potential flaw(s) in my logic?

Here is the equation (Wikipedia (3)):

[image]

I get A and B values from a table in a textbook (2).

[image]

and I get the secondary electron coefficient gamma_SE by taking the average proton energy (5 keV) from a publication (3):

[image]

So approximately 0.75. Plugging everything into my Matlab code:

```
%User inputs
GamSE = 0.75; %Determined by taking an average from an experiment

%Constants
A = 4.8; %cm^-1*Torr^-1
B = 136; %V*cm^-1*Torr^-1
x = logspace(-2,3,10000); %For plotting
y = (B.*x)./(log(A.*x) - log(log(1 + 1/GamSE)));

%Plotting
loglog(x,y)
hold on
grid on
title('Paschen Cruve for H2')
xlabel('p*d (Torr-cm)')
ylabel('Vb (V)')
xlim([10^-1 10^3])
ylim([10 10^5])
hold off
```

And the result of this code is:

[image]

Comparing this to experiment (2):

[image]

..and the wiki page [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htkhA.png):

[image]

The minimum value for my curve is a whole order of magnitude less essentially. So I tried dividing all my x-values (p*d values) by 10 and found the curve to match. But this doesn't make sense to me why I would need to do this when all the units are correct without doing that. So I am stuck as to what is going on.

(1) - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paschen%27s_law

(2) - Principles of Plasma Discharges and Materials Processing - Lieberman

(3) - Secondary electron emission from solid hydrogen and deuterium resulting from incidence of keV electrons and hydrogen ions, https://doi.org/10.1063/1.324035

Comment: Perhaps some keV vs eV and cm vs m conversions?

Comment: @JonCuster I verified that all the units for givens and what was plugged into the equation was correct, but maybe you can see something I missed.

Answer (score 0):

A quick check shows the issue is with units in the values you are inputting. The equation in Wikipedia uses m, Pa, and V, while the values you are inputting are cm and Torr.

I used Symbolic Math Toolbox to verify that with those inputs the units are consistent.

Should be an easy conversion of A and B.

```
syms A  B p d 

sympref('FloatingPointOutput',true);

gm = 0.75

u = symunit;

Vb =(B*u.V/(u.m*u.Pa)*p*u.Pa*d*u.m)/(log(A*u.m^-1*u.Pa^-1*p*u.Pa*d*u.m)-log(log(1+1/gm)))

var = checkUnits(Vb)

A2 = unitConvert(4.8*u.cm^-1*u.Torr^-1,1/(u.m*u.Pa))
```